# asp.net server session null after 2nd user login

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.net (vb) site where after login, i save the userid in a session (like i always do in php as well) and refresh the page.
Simply:

```
Session("UserID")=1
```

This is working fine with the first user. If another user login from different computer while the first still logged in, the userid goes into the session with no problem like

```
Session("UserID")=2
```

...but after i reload the page, the session of the 2nd user is empty. 
I always used sessions in php but seems in asp this doesn't work the same way. Could someone explain please what is the reason of this behavior in asp and what should i do ?

EDIT:
My web.config if helps:

```
    <configuration>
  <location path="ScriptResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LoadEJResourcesFromAssembly" value="true" />
    <add key="EJResources" value="jsrender:true;themes:true;" />
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
      <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>      
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="hu-HU" uiCulture="hu-HU"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms protection="All" loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="180" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89"/>
        <add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="webopt" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms"
          assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" />
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add tagPrefix="ej" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web" assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
        <add tagPrefix="ej" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web" assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
        <add tagPrefix="ej" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Models"
          assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
        <add tagPrefix="ej" namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.DataVisualization.Models"
          assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version=15.3460.0.26, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom/>
```

Comment: There are various ways to configure how sessions work in ASP.net, by default it uses a cookie on client side. Is user2 allowing cookies?

Comment: yes, both user allows cookies. Both users can log in separately aswell, but no 2 users can be logged in the same time. Seems i can not save 2 sessions with same name on windows server

Comment: obviously it should work. Are you running under IIS express (VS)? What does it say about session in your web.config?

Comment: I experience the same problem in VS and on the server (Windows server 2012) as well. Nothing about sessions in my web.config. Should i include anything there to make sure it will let multiple users connect or something?

Comment: can you output this value? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID. It should be unique per user. If it is consistent for each user but not the same for both, then it must be something else in your code clearing it.

Comment: This should work "out of the box". By default in asp.net, like php, sessions are unique to each user (browser instance). What else is happening on page reload? Is the Session assignment happening again but without a value this time? Have you set a break point and stepped through the code in debug mode on page reload to see what happens?

Comment: "This should work "out of the box" that's what i thought, that's why it's so weird to me. I guess something in my webconfig then

Comment: the two sessionIDs are different

Comment: for the 2nd user, if you refresh page after login, like you said, does the sessionID change? If not, it must be in your code on server. If it does, it may be in your client code

Comment: The sessionid doesn't change if i refresh the page. It's same for the same user.
" Have you set a break point and stepped through "
Yes, i have stepped trough and the session is set after login, but its empty after reload
Weird thing is, i use form authentication and that working fine. Both users are authenticated only the session is empty of the 2nd one

Comment: by default, session state is stored in the application cache object. Anything on server that affects the cache?

Comment: Shouldn't be. I didn't set anything. Everything is on default as it was installed.

Comment: I never had issue with just 2 users, but InProc session state was never that reliable for me. Try state server and see if that fixes it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-2-configure-asp-net-settings

Comment: something must be with my app as i just tried with new project and in the newly created project is working fine.

Comment: i got it working. sessionState was missing from my web.config.
Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the case, it most likely is being caused by a misconfiguration of the sessionState in your web.config.  From the docs:

```
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="number of minutes"
    cookieName="session identifier cookie name"
    cookieless=
         "[true|false|AutoDetect|UseCookies|UseUri|UseDeviceProfile]"
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="[True|False]"
    sessionIDManagerType="session manager type"
    sqlConnectionString="sql connection string"
    sqlCommandTimeout="number of seconds"
    allowCustomSqlDatabase="[True|False]"
    useHostingIdentity="[True|False]"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=server:port"
    stateNetworkTimeout="number of seconds"
    customProvider="custom provider name"
    compressionEnabled="[True|False]"
    sqlConnectionRetryInterval="number of seconds">
    <providers>...</providers>
</sessionState>
```

The most likely culprits are "mode" and "cookieless". For testing, use mode=InProc (it is the default).  If mode=Off you will have issues and if mode=Custom the custom implementation may be broken.

If there is a cookieless option set, it could fail if set to UseDeviceProfile. If the machines are identical and behind the same NAT device, there will likely be a collision of device profile. To test, set to false or delete the setting to use the default.

The other settings mostly don't apply if you use InProc and cookieless is false, except maybe cookieName, which is unlikely to break things.

EDIT: I could not find good instructions for setting up the ASP.net state server on stack overflow. I do recommend this method because the InProc method has seemed to me to lose sessions somewhat unpredictably.

- Launch "Services" app in windows (same on Win10 and Win Server)
- Find "ASP.NET State Service"
- Right click and change startup type to "Automatic"
- Also, to start immediately, right click on the service and choose Start.
- In your web.config, set sessionState tag as below

  <sessionState
      mode="StateServer" 
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" 
      cookieless="UseCookies" 
      timeout="25">
- sessionState tag goes within the <system.web> section.

Comment: Yep it's working perfectly now. Thank you very much!